# How to convert this using regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

as novice in regular expression , I have a problem and I am not sure how to solve this,

```
$string = '15Mar2009(sun)';
$pattern = '/((\d+){1,2})((\w+){3})((\d+){4})((w+){3})/i';
$replacement = '${1} ${2} ${3} ';
echo "\n";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
echo "\n";
```

I need output in this format `15 Mar 2009 sun`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the below regex,

```
^(\d{2})([A-Za-z]{3})(\d{4})\(([^)]*)\)$
```

Substitution,

```
$1 $2 $3 $4
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/47)

PHP code would be,

```
<?php
$string = '15Mar2009(sun)';
$pattern = '~^(\d{2})([A-Za-z]{3})(\d{4})\(([^)]*)\)$~';
$replacement = '$1 $2 $3 $4';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?> //=> 15 Mar 2009 sun
```

Comment: thanks @Avinash, You saved my time and also taught me.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `+` modifier already and then you are using quantifier `{}` which simply doesn't makes sense.

You need to remove the `+`s and escape `(` and `)` by a backslash to match them literally.

So, use this regex:

```
(\d{1,2})(\w{3})(\d{4})\(\w{3}\)
```

And replace it with:

```
$1 $2 $3 $4
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove extra `+` and to match brackets escape them in last part:

```
$pattern = '/(\d{1,2})(\w{3})(\d{4})\((w{3})\)/';
```